# Does Elastic Beanstalk run one node thread per instance?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Normally if you configure a node server yourself you set up pm2 which spawns several “workers”. I don’t see anywhere in the AWS docs where elastic beanstalk does this or allows for configuration of multiple “workers” or some kind of single server “cluster”, so is it always just one thread per instance? That would be kind of silly on an instance w multiple cores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is a single thread. Elastic Beanstalk just executes [your Procfile](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/nodejs-configuration-procfile.html) to start an application which is  `node app.js` by default. You would have to custom develop your application to use more "workers":

- [Running multiple Node.JS processes per instance on AWS Elastic Beanstalk](https://medium.com/@devopszero/running-multiple-node-js-processes-per-instance-on-aws-elastic-beanstalk-b756af567f45)

Comment: Thanks, that is good to know! This info was hard to come by. Hm, now the question is is it worth doing the custom configuration for a big instance or am I better off using the default configuration and just spawning a bunch of small instances. Probably the latter.